# Load the page first (css, html), then render it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site that takes data from `localStorage` and then applies some tweaks to the CSS by appending a CSS file to the `<head>` - However, it takes too long and the user can see the CSS changing which I feel is unfriendly. Is it possible to load all the jQuery, CSS, HTML and then render the page?

Comment: i don't think it is possible may be you can hide your whole html page and then show it once all the appending css and jquery processing is over...

Comment: I am not sure though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If jQuery is not loaded:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

First, hide all the page

```
<body style="display: none;">
```

With jQuery show all, when all files are loaded:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").show();
});
</script>
```

or with jQuery instead $:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  $("body").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this on a WordPress theme. Put the `<script>` before `</body>` but didn't work. I get this error on the console `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`Any idea?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded?  Added two lines to the beginning of my first answer

Comment: Sorry, I put "#body" , but should be "body" (It's a tag not an id)

Comment: It's still not working unfortunately. The console error is still there.

Comment: Yes! That worked like a charm. Is there anyway I can add a fadeIn effect to it?

Comment: try adding the "slow" parameter: $("body").show("slow");